# Expansion of the universe a thermodynamic process or not?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, universe, space-expansion

1. Can the expansion of the universe be thought of as a thermodynamic process?
2. If so, is it a closed system?
3. Is it a reversible system?

Comment: Yes. Yes. No...

Comment: You have to remember that the Universe is not in thermodynamic equilibrium!

Comment: Is it a closed system, given that the longer we wait, the farther we can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universe is not currently in (or even close to) thermodynamic equilibrium, so the kind of thermodynamics we teach in a first course (often called "equilibrium thermodynamics") is right out.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Yes**, but, the system is not in thermodynamic equilibrium, as said by @dmckee or @HritikNarayan, since the processes happen very fast, creating additional entropy;
2. **Yes**, up to the experimental data of the moment, although we have theories that deal with the interaction among universes;
3. **No**, because the reasons of my first answer (the thermodynamic processes are not quasi-statistic ones).